# Magento 2: Setting up mini cart loader overlay

Tags: magento2

How can I create the mini cart loader overlay when customer deleting an item?

I've found js files but I can't figure out where should I put code lines to activate and disable loader overlay.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the js `/magento/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/sidebar.js`

on Events Click, you will find the function `_removeItem` which calls `_ajax` function.

In the `_ajax` function you will find `beforeSend` and `complete` methods which you can use to enable and disable loader overlay.

For instance,

```
/** @inheritdoc */
beforeSend: function () {
    elem.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $("#loader").show();
},

/** @inheritdoc */
complete: function () {
    elem.attr('disabled', null);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#loader").hide();
    }, 3000);
}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: You are awesome!